# Dates in Ascending order based on multiple columns for calculating Opening and Closing balance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am developing an application for a shop. In this business it is possible that in any day there is No item sold but there is expense or  bill paid to supplier and vice versa.Formula for calculating closing balance is as:

```
Closing_Balance = Opening_Balance + Income - Expense - Bill
```

I have following tables

**SupplierPayments**

```
DateOfPayment   Bill

2018-06-01      4000
2018-06-01      9000
2018-06-19      2000
2018-06-19      6000
2019-03-28      3000
2019-03-29      5000
```

**Expensis**

```
DateOfExpense   Expense

2018-08-14      2,000
2019-02-26      8,000
2019-03-28      2000
2019-03-29      2000
```

**Income**

```
DateSold        Income

2018-09-27      24,000
2018-10-17      8,000
2019-01-01      13,000
2019-03-28      10,000
```

I used following 
**SQL Server Query**

```
with Income( DateSold, Income ) as (
    select DateSold,isnull(sum(TotalBill),0)
    from SalesInvoice group by DateSold
), SupplierPayments( DateOfPayment,Bill ) as(
    select DateOfPayment,isnull(sum(BillPaidAmount),0) 
    from SupplyInvoicePaymentHistory group by DateOfPayment
), Expensis( DateOfExpense, Expense ) as(
    select Date ,isnull(sum(Amount),0) 
    from GeneralExpense group by Date
), t as (
    select i.DateSold
        ,e.DateOfExpense
        ,sp.DateOfPayment
        ,i.income
        , e.Expense
        ,sp.Bill
        , sum(isnull(i.income,0)-(isnull(e.Expense,0)+isnull(sp.Bill,0))) over (order by i.DateSold,e.DateOfExpense,sp.DateOfPayment) as closing_balance 
    from income i 
    full outer  join expensis e on e.DateOfExpense = i.DateSold 
    full outer join SupplierPayments sp on sp.DateOfPayment=e.DateOfExpense

) 
select m.DateSold
    ,m.DateOfExpense
    ,m.DateOfPayment
    ,isnull(m.opening_balance,0) as Opening_Balance
    ,isnull(m.Income,0) as Income
    ,isnull(m.Expense,0) as Expensis
    ,isnull(m.Bill,0) as SupplierPayments
    ,isnull(m.closing_balance,0) as Closing_Balance
from (
    select DateSold
        ,DateOfExpense
        ,DateOfPayment
        ,lag(closing_balance,1,0) over (order by DateSold, DateOfExpense,DateOfPayment) as opening_balance,Income
        , Expense
        ,closing_balance
        ,Bill 
    from t
) as m
```

**Output**

```
DateSold    ExpenseDate PaymentDate Opening Income  Expense Bill  Closing
NULL         NULL       2018-06-01  0        0      0       4,000 -4,000
NULL         NULL       2018-06-19  -4000    0      0       2,000 -6,000      
NULL        2018-08-14  NULL        -6,000   0      2,000   0     -8,000
NULL        2019-02-26  NULL        -8,000   0      8,000   0     -16,000
NULL        2019-03-29  2019-03-29  -16,000  0      2000    5000  -23,000
2018-09-27  NULL        NULL        -23,000  24,000 0       0     1,000
2018-10-17  NULL        NULL        1,000    8,000  0       0     9,000
2019-01-01  NULL        NULL        9,000    13,000 0       0     22,000
2019-03-28  2019-03-28  2019-03-28  22,000   10,000 2000    3000  27,000
```

The `Closing` balance is wrong because of the ordering of Dates Columns. i want the following output in which Date is in ascending order based on 3 dates columns

**Required Result**

```
DateSold    ExpenseDate PaymentDate Opening Income  Expense Bill  Closing
NULL        NULL        2018-06-01  0        0      0       4,000 -4,000
NULL        NULL        2018-06-19  -4000    0      0       2,000 -6,000      
NULL        2018-08-14  NULL        -6,000   0      2,000   0     -8,000
2018-09-27  NULL        NULL        -8,000   24,000 0       0     16,000
2018-10-17  NULL        NULL        16,000   8,000  0       0     24,000
2019-01-01  NULL        NULL        24,000   13,000 0       0     37,000
NULL        2019-02-26  NULL        37,000   0      8,000   0     29,000
2019-03-28  2019-03-28  2019-03-28  29,000   10,000 2000    3000  34,000
NULL        2019-03-29  2019-03-29  34,000   0      2000    5000  29,000
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: Ok, then you can use first query I proposed :)

Answer (score 1):

I think `union all` with `group by` might be a better approach:

```
select dte, sum(bill) as bill, sum(expense) as expense,
       sum(income) as income,
       sum(income - expense - bill) over (order by dte) - (income - expense - bill) as opening_balance
       sum(income - expense - bill) over (order by dte) as closing_balance
from ((select DateOfPayment as dte, Bill, 0 as expense, 0 as income
       from SupplierPayments
      ) union all
      (select DateOfExpense, 0, Expense, 0 as income
       from expenses
      ) union all
      (select datesold, 0, 0, income
       from income
      )
     ) d
group by dte
order by dte;
```

The query is a little simpler than a `full join` query, because you don't have to deal with so many `NULL` values.  More importantly, if one of the tables has two entries on the same date, this produces the correct answer.

Comment: You said right if any table has more than one entry then the ovpre complex query produce wrong opening , closing balance

Comment: please send  the full query that produces result as  shown in my "Required Result" tale having Opening and Closing balance

Comment: please help me to find out "Required Result" tale having Opening and Closing balance

Comment: Your query also does not produce the correct opening and closing balance in case if one of the tables has two entries on the same date. Please Let me know the correct query

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
declare @SupplierPayments table(DateOfPayment date, Bill int);
insert into @SupplierPayments values
('2018-06-01', 4000),
('2018-06-19', 2000),
('2019-03-28', 3000),
('2019-03-29', 5000);

declare @Expensis table(DateOfExpense date, Expense int);
insert into @Expensis values
('2018-08-14',2000),
('2019-02-26',8000),
('2019-03-28',2000),
('2019-03-29',2000);

declare @Income table(DateSold date, Income int);
insert into @Income values
('2018-09-27',24000),
('2018-10-17',8000),
('2019-01-01',13000),
('2019-03-28',10000);
```

To get `Closing` column it's enough to use your formula per each row (without need of `Opening column`).
Then, to get `Closing` values, it's enough to use cumulative sum on column with that formula (just take a look at the query).
Cumulative sum can be easily achieved with `sum` function with `over` clause with `order by`.

```
select EventDate, DateOfExpense, DateOfPayment, DateSold, Income, Expense, Bill,
       sum(Income - Expense - Bill)
         over (order by EventDate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) Opening,
       sum(Income - Expense - Bill)
         over (order by EventDate) Closing
from (
    select coalesce(coalesce(DateOfPayment, DateOfExpense), DateSold) EventDate, * 
    from (
      select DateOfPayment, sum(coalesce(Bill, 0)) Bill from @SupplierPayments group by DateOfPayment
    ) sp 
    full join (
      select DateOfExpense, sum(coalesce(Expense, 0)) Expense from @Expensis group by DateOfExpense
    ) e on sp.DateOfPayment = e.DateOfExpense
    full join (
      select DateSold, sum(coalesce(Income, 0)) Income from @Income group by DateSold
    ) i on sp.DateOfPayment = i.DateSold
) a order by EventDate
```

Comment: But i need Opening column as well please @Michał Turczyn

Comment: Using SQL Server 2012. over clause (window functions) is  available

Comment: if any table has more than one entry then the results are not right. Please modify query accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @shakeel To resolve that issue, you need to group results by date in your dates to provide uniqueness of dates :) Check updated answer :)

Comment: Still Not getting the correct opening and closing if any table has two or more records having same date. You may Check it

Comment: Please see updated "SupplierPayments" table to clear my question. Note that multiple rows have same date. Now what will be the correct query

Comment: @shakeel Please update also required result, as it don't match your updated input.